# Intersections in linestrings using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I need to get the intersections of streets and create a graph, so to get the intersections I use this select:

```
SELECT
    ST_GeometryType(geom), geom
 FROM (
        SELECT  a.gid, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
        FROM
            streets a
        JOIN
            streets b
        ON
            ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.gid != b.gid AND a.gid > b.gid
  ) as foo
```

[image]

But this query returns different types of geometries, and some rows are ST_GeometryCollection type.

[image]

I tried to use this select:

```
SELECT ST_geometrytype(geom), geom
FROM (
    SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom as geom
    FROM
         streets a
    JOIN
         streets b
    ON
         ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.gid != b.gid AND a.gid > b.gid
) as foo
```

[image]

When I used this query many LineStrings were "broken" in short LineStrings.

[image]

[image]

You can see that LineStrings have some common subset, but I think that all subset would be only one LineStrings, do I wrong?

If the subsets is right, I need to know how to join the subsets into only LineString (the same intersection). I need this to then create a graph, the LineStrings will be my vertex.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to merge multiple linestrings or create a graph. ST_LineMerge might be what you are looking for, for the first part. A minor point, but if you have a.gid > b.gid then you don't need a.gid != b.gid (though the query planner will remove this, of course).

Comment: you are trying to *node a network*, that is, you want vertices at intersections, as the core topology for a routing graph (?). I suggest to have a look at *pgRouting* as a routing extension to PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and the function `pgr_nodeNetwork` in particular.

Comment: `ST_Intersection` works differently than you seem to expect; it doesn't return points of intersection *per se*, but **any geometric shape** that two geometries have in common. thus your results.

Comment: @JohnPowell, first I need to merge multiple linestrings. I tried to use ST_LineMerge, but it did not work. I want to merge just the linestrings that has a common path. How can I do this ? Thanks

Comment: @ThingumaBob I don't know about pgRouting, I'll look for it, thanks.

Comment: @ThingumaBob and I know it returns different types, I want both points as linestrings. But my linestrings are weird, some linestrings are ok, but some are broken.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by common path, but, you could use GROUP BY path_number or similar.

Comment: Hi, i think you have all you need in the comment : First, try to set your data properly with LineMerge and then have a look at Pgrouting to create the graph you are looking for.